# IPv6 handling when using Direct protocol v4.00

Tags: opayo

I tried turning on Direct protocol v4.00 today, however I hit a snagging point with IP address handling. Some client IP addresses are IPv6 addresses e.g: `2a02:c7f:d192:dc00:de4:a84d:aab5:8225` (i've tweaked this address a little)

When I send these IPv6 addresses through I get the following error:

```
VPSProtocol=4.00
Status=INVALID
StatusDetail=3067 : The ClientIPAddress is too long.
VPSTxId={03F24DE5-60E6-FE73-0BFA-SOMETHING}
```

If I omit the IP address altogether, I get the following error:

```
VPSProtocol=4.00
Status=INVALID
StatusDetail=3333 : The ClientIPAddress is missing.
VPSTxId={983A157B-8866-A6C9-A4AC-SOMETHING}
```

So, what am I meant to do when presented with an IPv6 address? Fall back to Direct protocol v3.00??

Comment: As a follow up, to answer my own question: until SagePay fix this, we've implemented the following: if the IP address is IPv6 (and can't be converted to an IPv4 ... some can), then we fall back to Direct protocol v3.00.